# CakePHP model association deep model contain

Tags: php, cakephp

I've been struggling with this problem for some time now, and have matched the associations with various other Models in my CakePHP applicaiton, but still can not get the result array to contain the associated ExpenseType.

Everything Starts with Property, which is defined as:

> var $recursive = 2;
>
> var $actsAs = array('Containable');

**Model Associations**

Property hasMany Bill

Bill belongsTo Property

Bill hasOne ExpenseType

ExpenseType belongsTo Bill

---

In My PropetiesController, I call and assign to $property:

> $this->Property->findById($id);

This results in:

```
Array
(
[Property] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [address] => **
        [bedrooms] => 2
        [bathrooms] => 1.5
        [square_footage] => 973
        [zip_code] => **
        [created] => 2013-08-13 18:30:34
        [modified] => 2013-08-15 19:08:32
    )

[Bill] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [expense_type_id] => 1
                [property_id] => 2
                [frequency] => monthly
                [start_date] => 2013-09-16
                [payee] => **
                [amount] => **
                [created] => 2013-08-20 19:57:41
                [modified] => 2013-08-20 20:57:02
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 4
                [expense_type_id] => 4
                [property_id] => 2
                [frequency] => monthly
                [start_date] => 2013-09-15
                [payee] => **
                [amount] => 195
                [created] => 2013-08-20 20:38:11
                [modified] => 2013-08-20 20:38:11
            )

    )
)
```

For the life of me, I can not get the array to contain the details of ExpenseType under Bill. Suggestions please!

UPDATE: When setting the contain method on the model, Cake now reports:

> Model "Bill" is not associated with model "ExpenseType"

**Bill Model**

```
    class Bill extends AppModel {
        /*******************
        * Variables        *
        *******************/
        var $actsAs = array('Containable');

        /*********************
        * Model Associations *
        **********************/
        public $belongsTo = array('Property');
        public $hasOne = array('ExpenseType');
    }
```

**ExpenseType Model**

```
class ExpenseType extends AppModel {
    /*******************
    * Variables        *
    *******************/
    var $actsAs = array('Containable');

    /*******************
    * Model Associations      *
    *******************/
    public $belongsTo = array('Bill');
}
```

**Table Structure**

- bills

  - id
  - expense_type_id
  - property_id
  - ...
- expense_types

  - id
  - name
  - description

Comment: Please post entire model code for both Bill and ExpenseType.

Comment: Maybe because you haven't specified the foreignkey. What is your table structure for those two tables?

Comment: Added table structure for relevant tables.

Comment: Also, please specify what version of cake you are using in the tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by making the following changes:

**Property Model**

Changed:

```
public $hasMany = array(
        'Bill' => array(
            'className' => 'bills',
            'foreign_key' => 'property_id',
            'dependent' => true
            )
        );
```

To:

> public $hasMany = array('Bill');

**Bill Model**

> public $belongsTo = array('Property', 'ExpenseType');

**ExpenseType Model**

> public $hasMany = array('Bill');

Seems the invalid association in the Property model was still allowing Bills to be queried, but somehow messed up the deeper associations. Not sure why it would work period.

Comment: Oh because `'className' => 'bills'` should have been `'className' => 'Bill'`. That'll do it! Way to go.

Comment: Exactly, not sure how Bills would even be queried. I would expect an error at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

1.) Move recursive to PropertiesController right before `findById`

```
$this-Property->recursive = 2;
```

2.) Use containable behavior on Bill and ExpenseType models

```
var $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

...then in PropertiesController do...

```
$this->Property->contain(array(
    'Bill' => array(
        'ExpenseType'
    )
));

$this->set('property', $this->Property->findById($id));
```

**UPDATE #1:**

Bill Model

```
class Bill extends AppModel {
    /*******************
    * Variables        *
    *******************/
    var $actsAs = array('Containable');


    /*********************
    * Model Associations *
    **********************/
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Property' => array(
            'className' => 'Property',
            'foreignKey' => 'property_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'ExpenseType' => array(
            'className' => 'ExpenseType',
            'foreignKey' => 'expense_type_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
    ); // end belongsTo
} // end Bill model
```

ExpenseType Model

```
class ExpenseType extends AppModel {
    /*******************
    * Variables        *
    *******************/
    var $actsAs = array('Containable');


    /*******************
    * Model Associations      *
    *******************/
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Bill' => array(
            'className' => 'Bill',
            'foreignKey' => 'expense_type_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
    ); // end hasMany

} // end ExpenseType model
```

then clear cache

Comment: Please see my update. Says Bill is not associated with ExpenseType

Comment: No change, still says not associated. See how frustrating this is :)

Comment: Hmm, I do deep contains all the time. Sometimes many more layers than this. I remember having this issue a lot when I started but I'm trying to recall what the solution(s) were. Sometimes it had to do with the naming conventions but yours appear correct.

Comment: I have figured it out, see my answer below. Thanks a lot for your help.